# Webmatrix - Update input value from querystring

Tags: forms, razor, webmatrix

i have a super quick question for you that i would imagine you could answer quickly. 
I have a search page on the web site that i'm building, that uses querystring parameters to change the search results.

I also want any querystring parameters to reflect the search form embedded on the same page. It works perfectly for input boxes. for example:

Edited code:

```
var proptype = db.Query("SELECT * FROM Property_Type");

string propertyType = "";

propertyType = Request.QueryString["propertyType"];
    <select name="propertytype">
      <option value="">Any</option>
      @foreach(var type in proptype){    
      <option value="@type.PropertyTypeID" selected="@(propertyType == type.PropertyTypeID)">@type.PropertyType</option>
      }
    </select>
```

Thanks, Gavin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To mark the value of an `<option>` within a `<select>` as selected, you use the `selected` property. At the simplest level, you can do this:

```
<select name="propertytype">
 <option value="">Any</option>
 <option value="villa" selected="@(propertyType == "villa")">Villa</option>
 <option value="apartment" selected="@(propertyType == "apartment")">Apartment</option>
</select>
```

This will evaluate each of the tests to true or false (only one should ever be true), and the Razor engine will write out `selected="selected"` on the appropriate element.

You should consider whether your property types should be stored in a database though. You should probably have a table of property types, and each property would use a foreign key to link to the appropriate one (or ones). This would change the entire way you write out your drop down list too, and actually simplify it somewhat. Your code would then be something like (obviously somewhat depending on your db schema and field names, etc):

```
<select name="propertytype">
 <option value="">Any</option>
 @foreach(var type in propertyTypesQuery)
 {
     <option value="@type.Id" selected="@(propertyType == type.Id)">@type.Name</option>
 }
</select>
```

And the bit where you get the value from the form element can be as simple as:

```
int propertyType = Request.Form["propertytype"].AsInt();
```

This will set it to zero if nothing was selected, and you can use that for your 'any' logic in your search system.

You can also use the `Html.DropDownList()` helper for an arguably cleaner version of this. See Mike Brind's article for some example code: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/196/WebMatrix-jQuery-Cascading-Dropdown-Lists

You are using the wrong variable name on your code too, you seem to have reused `numBedrooms`, but I suspect it is a copy/paste error. To be clear: `numBedrooms = Request.QueryString["propertyType"];` should be `propertyType = Request.QueryString["propertyType"];`.

Comment: i think you're right, i need to add my property types to a second table in my database. this will also make it much easier should i ever need to add an additional property type. it'll take a bit of effort to change, but i think it'll be worth while. Once done, i'll still need to use the "selected" attribute right? just reference the propertyType ID instead of the string?

Comment: I'll put in an edit for the kind of thing you would do with the database version - and yes I would suggest it is worth your time doing that work now - it will pay dividends in the future.

Comment: Hey, i've done as you suggested, and i'm getting the error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'short'". I'll post my edited code above